# Create Unique Reference for person but grouped by account

Tags: mysql, reference, unique

I'm trying to generate a unique reference per person attached to an account. This is in a MySQL SELECT statement. Normally, as I have a unique reference for both person and account, I'd just concat them. However, I'm restricted to a range of 0 to 9999 so I need to create a reference which is unique at account level.

I created the following:

```
    SELECT @n := @n + 1 n,
    ID,
    NAME
    FROM table1, (SELECT @n := 0) m
    ORDER BY ID,NAME
```

which provide the following:

```
   1    1027000001  Mr a
   2    1027000001  Mr b
   3    1027000001  Mr c
   4    1062000001  Mr d
   5    1062000001  Mr e
```

But what I would actually like is:

```
   1    1027000001  Mr a
   2    1027000001  Mr b
   3    1027000001  Mr c
   1    1062000001  Mr d
   2    1062000001  Mr e
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: So, where is that MySQL select statement? Also, can't you just use PersonID?

Comment: @GolezTrol - Sorry, I wasn't clear, I meant it is for a select statement, I haven't written it. And the data above is just example data to illustrate my request - the actual person ID is 10 characters long

Comment: Original question edited to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, but for the variable to get increment you need to check if the `previous ID` is same as `current ID` something as

```
select 
r,ID,NAME from (
 select 
 @rn:= if(@prev_id = ID, @rn+1,1) as r,
 ID,
 NAME,
 @prev_id:= ID
 from table1 , (select @rn:=0,@prev_id:= null)x
 order by ID
)x
```

Comment: Thank you so much - that's exactly what I was after.